# how can i echo a line containing single quotes?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, echo

I want to echo a line containing single quotes but when I am echoing it, the output comes out without the quotes inside that line. I am using this  `echo rule_files: [ '${path.config}/folder/*.py' ]` and the output is

> rule_files: [ ${path.config}/folder/*.py ]

I want the output to include the single quotes around the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes:

```
echo rule_files: [ \'${path.config}/folder/*.py\' ]
```

or

```
echo rule_files: [ \''${path.config}/folder/*.py'\' ]
```

Comment: The above one doesn't work. It gives an error of bad substitution. The second one seems to be working. Thank you.